# Interpret WinSCP log file to find transferred file size

Tags: logging, sftp, winscp

I have a text winscp log as follows

```
. 2020-03-07 10:01:31.776 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2020-03-07 10:01:31.776 Using SFTP protocol.
. 2020-03-07 10:01:31.776 Doing startup conversation with host.
> 2020-03-07 10:01:31.776 Type: SSH_FXP_INIT, Size: 5, Number: -1
< 2020-03-07 10:01:33.370 Type: SSH_FXP_VERSION, Size: 5, Number: -1
. 2020-03-07 10:01:33.370 SFTP version 3 negotiated.
. 2020-03-07 10:01:33.370 We believe the server has signed timestamps bug
. 2020-03-07 10:01:33.370 We will use UTF-8 strings until server sends an invalid UTF-8 string as with SFTP version 3 and older UTF-8 strings are not mandatory
. 2020-03-07 10:01:33.370 Getting current directory name.
. 2020-03-07 10:01:33.370 Getting real path for '.'
> 2020-03-07 10:01:33.370 Type: SSH_FXP_REALPATH, Size: 10, Number: 16
< 2020-03-07 10:01:33.370 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 70, Number: 16
. 2020-03-07 10:01:33.370 Real path is '/sftp.[Redacted]'
. 2020-03-07 10:01:33.370 Startup conversation with host finished.
< 2020-03-07 10:01:33.370 Script: Active session: [1] [Redacted]
> 2020-03-07 10:01:33.370 Script: lcd "[Redacted]"
< 2020-03-07 10:01:33.370 Script: [Redacted]
> 2020-03-07 10:01:33.385 Script: put myFile.csv -nopreservetime
. 2020-03-07 10:01:33.385 Copying 1 files/directories to remote directory "[Redacted]" - total size: 61,938
. 2020-03-07 10:01:33.385 PrTime: No; PrRO: No; Rght: rw-r--r--; PrR: No (No); FnCs: N; RIC: 0100; Resume: S (102400); CalcS: No; Mask:
. 2020-03-07 10:01:33.385 TM: B; ClAr: No; RemEOF: No; RemBOM: No; CPS: 0; NewerOnly: No; InclM: ; ResumeL: 0
. 2020-03-07 10:01:33.385 AscM: *.*html; *.htm; *.txt; *.php; *.php3; *.cgi; *.c; *.cpp; *.h; *.pas; *.bas; *.tex; *.pl; *.js; .htaccess; *.xtml; *.css; *.cfg; *.ini; *.sh; *.xml
. 2020-03-07 10:01:33.385 Getting real path for '[Redacted]'
> 2020-03-07 10:01:33.385 Type: SSH_FXP_REALPATH, Size: 58, Number: 272
< 2020-03-07 10:01:33.385 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 70, Number: 272
. 2020-03-07 10:01:33.385 Real path is '[Redacted]'
. 2020-03-07 10:01:33.385 File: 'myFile.csv' [2020-03-07T10:01:31.074Z] [61938]
. 2020-03-07 10:01:33.417 Copying "myFile.csv" to remote directory started.
. 2020-03-07 10:01:33.417 Binary transfer mode selected.
. 2020-03-07 10:01:33.417 Opening remote file.
> 2020-03-07 10:01:33.417 Type: SSH_FXP_OPEN, Size: 85, Number: 515
< 2020-03-07 10:01:33.557 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 10, Number: 515
> 2020-03-07 10:01:33.557 Type: SSH_FXP_WRITE, Size: 32764, Number: 1030
. 2020-03-07 10:01:33.573 1 skipped SSH_FXP_WRITE, SSH_FXP_READ, SSH_FXP_DATA and SSH_FXP_STATUS packets.
> 2020-03-07 10:01:33.573 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 10, Number: 1540
< 2020-03-07 10:01:33.588 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 32, Number: 1030
< 2020-03-07 10:01:33.588 Status code: 0
< 2020-03-07 10:01:33.588 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 32, Number: 1286
< 2020-03-07 10:01:33.588 Status code: 0
< 2020-03-07 10:01:33.667 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 32, Number: 1540
< 2020-03-07 10:01:33.667 Status code: 0
. 2020-03-07 10:01:33.667 Transfer done: 'myFile.csv' => '[Redacted]' [61938]
. 2020-03-07 10:01:33.667 Copying finished: Transferred: 61,938, Elapsed: 0:00:00, CPS: 267,853/s
> 2020-03-07 10:01:33.667 Script: exit
. 2020-03-07 10:01:33.667 Script: Exit code: 0
. 2020-03-07 10:01:33.667 Closing connection.
. 2020-03-07 10:01:33.667 Sending special code: 12
. 2020-03-07 10:01:33.667 Sent EOF message
```

Is it possible from this log to find the file size of myFile.csv that was transferred?

I might guess that this is what the  `Transferred` field in the line `Copying finished: Transferred: 61,938, Elapsed: 0:00:00, CPS: 267,853/s` contains - is that right? if so, what are the units?

I have been unable to find online any documentation on what all these lines of log actually mean - some of them are plain English enough to be understood, but many contain terms and references that I do not understand. All searches for specific codes have been successful (special code 12 closes the connection for instance), but I cannot find any help determining the file size of the file that was successfully transferred - all such queries lead to questions about the log file size, not the transferred file.

Any help greatly appreciated. If you know of any documentation on reading the logs, a link would also be really helpful!

EDIT: To be clear, I need to interpret the logs that have been produced in the past; this is not a question about in future using the logs to return the file size. I would like to know the file size that was transferred on some specific dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In future, I would try to avoid trying to interpret WinSCP session log files.

Use [XML logging instead](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/logging_xml).

Or use [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) instead of plain scripting.

However, if you are stuck with the log, you can see the file size in the following line:

```
. 2020-03-07 10:01:33.667 Transfer done: 'myFile.csv' => '[Redacted]' [61938]
```

in this case, the file size is 61938.